# How can I load embedded textures within a fbx file with FBX SDK?

Tags: c++, textures, fbx

I'm trying to make my own FBX importer using FBX SDK, OpenGL 3.3 (c++).

I know that you can embed textures within a fbx file. That way you can work with a single fbx file without any texture images which is very convenient.

However, assuming that I have a fbx file with textures embedded, how can I extract the textures out of the file so I can send them to my fragment shader? Are there any classes or documentations I can look at?

Comment: [This](https://github.com/nem0/OpenFBX) turned up in the first few results for 'fbx importer'.

Comment: Or did you really just mean "how do i upload images to the GPU?" A good introduction can be found on [open.gl](https://open.gl/textures)

Comment: Hello. Please share your fbx importer code :_)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm assuming you're using FBX SDK class `FbxImporter` to open and extract the data in the FBX file. In that case, whenever you tell the SDK to import a file, it will create a folder with the name xxx.fbm (where xxx is your file's name). You'll find this folder in the same directory as your file. That's where it also automatically extracts all embedded media like textures. All you have to do is look in that folder and see if there're any texture files (e.g. jpg, png, etc.) and read them however you want into your application.

Comment: Oh my god this is the information I was looking for thank you so much!